# When to use "innerText" over "value" of an element preferrably, and vice versa? HTML, JS

Tags: javascript, html, button, innertext, nodevalue

let's say I want to build an HTML button with a text on it, like "Click me!" - and then access it in my JS app. I could set the text of that button as a node value, or as innerText, for example (I know, there are also innerHtml and InnerTextContent, but those are irrelevant for me in this case) - What I did not yet fully understand is - When do I use "innerText", when do I use "value", to set this text, preferrably?

I do know and (think I) understand the difference between them both, but I don't know yet when to prefer the one or the other. Is there anything like a rule of thumb for this issue? Any great dis-/advantages?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:**
Thanks for your answers so far, wow that was fast! :)
Just to clarify things and avoid misunderstandings - as I said above, my question is not about InnerHTML or TextContent or all the other possible ways to get text on a button.

I am really only referring to the different usecases between "value" and "innerText" with that goal to set a visible button text as "Click Me!" right on that button. I am looking for a best practice rule for this, you could say. :)

I think, TJ Crowder answered this really well, thank you TJ and of course, thank you anybody else for your time and help! :) As I am new to this platform, I am not yet allowed to give you guys a like. So FEEL it please. :D Thanks!

Comment: You should use `.textContent` instead of `innerText` anyway. And in general, you should avoid `innerHTML` because it triggers an expensive reparse and will break DOM element object-references.

Answer (score 1):

You only use `value` on *form controls* (`input`, `button`, `select`, and `textarea`). For any other element, if you want its text, use `textContent` or `innerText` (or, depending on your use case, `innerHTML`).

The only tricky one there is `button`, which is the only form control that has *both* a `value` *and* text. The `value` of a `button` is the value that will be submitted if that button submits the form it's in. The *text* is what the user sees as the button caption. Here's an example:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
console.log(`The button's value is: ${btn.value}`);
console.log(`The button's textContent is: ${btn.textContent}`);
```

```html
<button value="42">Forty-Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` refers to an attribute of a tag (Text based controls like `<input type="text">`, `<textarea>` etc. And many `<input>` form controls), while `innerHTML` refers to the HTML content between a tag's beginning and end.

Example `<span id="oSpan">myText</span>` now `oSpan.innerHTML` is `myText`. And like this textbox `<input id="oText" value="some text"/>` now `oText.value` is the `some text` which is in the textbox.

Comment: *"`value` refers to an attribute of a tag"* No, it doesn't. It refers to the *current value* of the form control, which isn't represented by any attribute at all. (The `value` attribute is the *default value* of a form control, not its current value.)

Answer (score 0):

when you use `<button>` you can use html inside button tag same as follow:

```
<button>
   <span>
      Click Me!
   </span>
</button>
```

but when you use . you cant use html inside  tag because it is a self closing tag and you can only set the value :

```
<input value="Click Me!" />
```

In javaScript when you set `value`, you are setting the value attribute of your selected DOM Element if that has 'value' attribute.

```
document.getElementById("inputButton").value = "Click Me!" //<input value="Click Me!" id="inputButton">
```

but with innerHtml you set HTML inside your selected DOM Element:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").innerHtml = '<span>Click Me!</span>' 
/*<button id="myButton">
   <span>Click Me!</span>
</button>*/
```

Comment: The `value` of a `button` can be different from its text.